# Histogram view of event value distribution

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

We're using Event Tracking to keep track of interactions with rich native advertising units. Events are fired any time a page containing the unit is loaded (to determine denominator for interaction %).

An event is also fired whenever an element within the unit is hovered-over by the user. The event category captures the name of the product, the event label the URL and the action the index of the element hovered-over. The event value is the time in seconds the unit was open for.

What I need is to get a more sophisticated view of the event value than sum and average. Ideally, I'd be able to look at a histogram to show the distribution of interaction times, or see the total interaction time for a given user in all elements in the unit.

It seems there's no way to get at this info within GA or a customized view, but would this be possible with the GA reporting API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GA does not currently support reporting of individual value of event values. You do have two choices:

1. If you only want the distribution then use [user timings](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingTiming). They conveniently go with your use case of tracking interaction timing. Don't forget to set the sample rate parameter or only 1% will be collected, unless you have already set `_setSiteSpeedSampleRate`.
2. Refactor your event so the timing value is a string of the event's action or label parameter. That way you can then use the API or export into a spreadsheet to generate a distribution. The benefit of this over the user timing is that you will have access to each individual unique value.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I was looking for something similar and my solution was to use a [hit-level custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#example-hit) to collect the numeric value. This allows you to assign a value to each and every individual event in the same way that category, action, and label are assigned.

If you do the bucketing upon collection, you can view your histogram within the reporting interface by changing from the "Data" view to the "Performance" view (horizontal bar charts). This can also be pulled from the reporting API.